# Drawing sets of boxes to display contents of arrays

Tags: java, optimization

This code draws two sets of 9 boxes on the screen to display the contents of two arrays.

How can I speed up, shorten and make the code more efficient?

```
    for (int x=0;x<3;x++){
        for (int y=0;y<3;y++){
            if (pattern[x][y]==1){
                g.setColor(colorrange.colb());
                g.fillRect(actlo+(x*size),actlo+(y*size),size,size);
            }
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                g.drawRect(actlo+(x*size),actlo+(y*size),size,size);

            if (patternb[x][y]==1){
                g.setColor(colorrange.colb());
                g.fillRect(actlo+(x*size),inlo+(y*size),size,size);
            }
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                g.drawRect(actlo+(x*size),inlo+(y*size),size,size);                 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplies can be pretty expensive within loops, so I minimized the use of them by precalculating where possible. It is also better to have the Y loop before the X loop to prevent cache misses (which wouldn't matter on a really small array like this but is a good practice). Consider this alternative:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
  final int yy = y * size;

  for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
  {
    final int xx = x * size;

    if(pattern[x][y] == 1)
    {
      g.setColor(colorrange.colb());
      g.fillRect(actlo + xx, actlo + yy, size, size);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawRect(actlo + xx, actlo + yy, size, size);

    if(patternb[x][y] == 1)
    {
      g.setColor(colorrange.colb());
      g.fillRect(actlo + xx, inlo + yy, size, size);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawRect(actlo + xx, inlo + yy, size, size);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, I hadn't thought of that...

Comment: Can you expand a little on why this is better in terms of cache coherency?

Comment: Corrected post (used incorrect terminology), thank you.